# Coded UI :How to select element from list which get closed when we select crosshair tool from Test builder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, coded-ui-tests

While automating my application i came across certain **button/ drop-down** list,When i click on that **list items** get displayed.

I'm trying to capture these list items using **coded Ui test builder** , but if i click crosshair icon then list will be closed.

I also tried to capture using WindowsLogo+i as it show on tool tip, but it will open setting window. (Windows 10)

so, Is there any why i can capture these type of elements ?

or can suggest code to select Item using Name property.

Comment: Ditch MS coded UI testing, and never touch the test builder if you want maintainable code.  Take a look at the the White framework from TestStack for your guide to a much happier life.

Comment: I agree with @LordWilmore. Also, if you want to spy your object properties you can use Inspect tool which is as part of Windows SDK. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @LordWilmore thanks for your suggestions , i really appreciate that. But, still is there any way i can capture such elements or we just can't map these elements and we must have to do hand code.

Comment: Take a look at the code that has been automatically generated where you are clicking on the control the first time.  That will give you the name or search properties for identifying the control, and the activation code to actually select it.  Then you can just add those lines in manually to your tests.  But again, this would take minutes for you to learn and achieve in a repeatable and understandable manner if you used White.

Comment: @LordWilmore thanks but i've already tried that  and this element can't be captured while recording. It record command as "Click 'Unknown Name' popup menu" for all list item.

Comment: White is not necessary and you can do similar stuff with direct coded ui or using something light weight to invert the code style.  codeduiexamples.com shows how to do this, there are also others like CUITe extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

1. In coded ui, you can inspect something at a higher level and use the navigation arrows to move around the actual inspected element.  Up arrow goes to container element.  Down element goes to child.  Left and right are for siblings.  Typically, you can use this to move around the UI element tree.
2. There is the [inspect tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) you can use from Microsoft.
3. Not sure if it changed, but you used to be able to place your mouse over an element and press Ctrl + Shift + Alt + i and it would inspect whatever was under the mouse.  Since it does not require clicking something else, it should not close your menu you are trying to inspect.

Per the comments above, I would recommend not using the test recorder at all and manually write your scripts instead.

Depending on how much you want to rely on another framework, you can choose a variety of options.

CodedUIExamples.com shows one way to do it which is 100% extension methods over coded ui and is completely interchangable with Coded UI (not bound to classes provided by the framework, only Coded UI).  I wrote this set of extensions.

Another great option is Coded UI Test Extension (CUITe) framework which does introduce a new set of classes to program against, but the programming model is much more intuitive.

White also has a better programming model similar to the first recommendation.

Overall, writing the scripts yourself is going to lead to more maintainable and re-usable components and is not difficult at all.